# pca.tranform(data) vs. data @ pca.components_.T

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

Given the matrix X, suppose we did:

```py
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=5).fit_transform(X)
```

Given a data matrix `data`, I would expect that the reduction to 5 dimensions is given by:

```py
data_reduced = data @ pca.components_.T
```

However, looking at [the code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/decomposition/_kernel_pca.py) of `pca.tranform()`, I see that it does something very different.

How do the two methods differ in high-lever terms?